# IE11 select drop-down when there is one element

Tags: select, internet-explorer-11

I have a select drop-down which has a single element and the drop down allows to select one or more. Even though I selected a value, I see a message

> You must choose an item from the list.

How do I get rid of this message anyways?

Comment: Did you wirte the website? What kind of error message is this? Are there errors on the browser console? And what has this question to do with programmanig? I'm voting to close this question as unclear. Please edit it and add all relvant source code.

Comment: It doesn't come on console, it appears on UI

Comment: i faced the same issue